# Error message occurs in Android studio when build APK

Tags: java, debugging, error-handling, android-gradle-plugin

I was complete my coding portion in Android Studio.  Then, I was run build APK and the sudden error occurs.

```
Caused by: com.android.builder.dexing.DexArchiveBuilderException: Error while dexing.
The dependency contains Java 8 bytecode. Please enable desugaring by adding the following to build.gradle
android {
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility 1.8
        targetCompatibility 1.8
    }
}

See https://developer.android.com/studio/write/java8-support.html for details. Alternatively, increase the minSdkVersion to 26 or above.
```

Answer (score 3):

As suggested in error log do one of following changes.

1. In app/build.gradle, add compileoptions for java 1.8 in android block.

   ```
   android {
        ...
        // Configure only for each module that uses Java 8
        // language features (either in its source code or
        // through dependencies).
        compileOptions {
          sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
          targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        }

   }
   ```
2. change minSDKVersion to 26.

   ```
   android {
        ...

        // change minSDKVersion to 26
        defaultConfig {
          ...
          minSdkVersion 26
         ....
      }
   }
   ```

Comment: It is "OR change minSDKVersion to 26". It is not needed if you add the compileOptions block.

Answer (score 3):

As suggested in the error message you just have to add this code to the build.gradle:

```
 android {
        compileOptions {
            sourceCompatibility 1.8
            targetCompatibility 1.8
        }
    }
```

or add as @Ranjan Kumar said, the min sdk android version:

```
 android {
          defaultConfig {
            minSdkVersion 26
         }
    }
```

Comment: Thank you so much, sir, for your help. I was depressed by thinking that I have to rewrite the whole program again.

Comment: It is "OR change minSDKVersion to 26". It is not needed if you add the compileOptions block.